# Symfony composer.json changing /public directory does not work for assets:install

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have deployed Symfony app moving all but `/public` to outside `root`, so it looks like:

/home/u593241563/domains/example.com/

- backend

  - ...
  - composer.json
- public

  - ...
  - index.php

Following [Symfony's docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/override_dir_structure.html#override-the-public-directory), I changed `composer.json` as follow:

```
 "scripts": {
    "auto-scripts": {
        "cache:clear": "symfony-cmd",
        "assets:install %PUBLIC_DIR%": "symfony-cmd"
    },
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "@auto-scripts"
    ]
},
"conflict": {
    "symfony/symfony": "*"
},
"extra": {
    "symfony": {
        "allow-contrib": false,
        "public-dir": "/home/u593241563/domains/example.com/public", *** ADDED THIS LINE ***
        "require": "4.4.*"
    }
}
```

Composer/Symfony do not seem to care and keeps using the same `PUBLIC_DIR`, throwing error whenever I run `composer install` or `composer require`:

> ["exception" => Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\InvalidArgumentException^ { …},"command" => "--ansi assets:install","message" => "The target directory "/home/u593241563/domains/example.com/backend/public" does not exist."]

Comment: I think that the path has to be relative to composer.json, not an absolute path as you are trying to use.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that,  but whatever I place at `public-dir` seems to be completely ignored. It gives the same error back, with the same path

Comment: Have you cleared cache? `rm -rf var/cache/*`, just in case?

Comment: Indeed, but that does not make a difference. On the other hand I found a solution ( see below)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the Symfony docs with the `public-dir` are not applicable for some reason.

What did resolve was to change the `assets-install` as below:

```
"assets:install /home/u593241563/domains/example.com/public_html": "symfony-cmd"
```

Also the `"public-dir":` was removed as pointless.